# How do I get content in wordpress to display on a certain date?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey people quick question, I'm trying to update a site for a client where they want certain numbers posted on certain dates. The code I wrote is:

```
<?php 
    if (is_page( XXXX )) && ((date('m') == 9)) && ((date('d') == 2)){

    echo 'To speak to an attorney about this practice area, please call XXX-XXX-XXXX';
    } elseif ((date('m') == 10)) && ((date('d') == 16)) {
    echo 'To speak to an attorney about this practice area, please call XXX-XXX-XXXX';
    }

 ?>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing? code isn't working. Please advise... and thank you in advance

Comment: @kba the content won't display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include all the conditions in the parentheses for the if statement:

```
<?php 
    if (is_page( 'XXXX' ) && (date('m') == 9) && (date('d') == 2)){
        echo 'To speak to an attorney about this practice area, please call XXX-XXX-XXXX';
    } 
    elseif ((date('m') == 10) && ((date('d') == 16))) {
        echo 'To speak to an attorney about this practice area, please call XXX-XXX-XXXX';
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: @MikeL5799 No problem - keep an eye on the parentheses you use :). If you found this answer helpful, please accept it as correct :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php 
    if (is_page( XXXX ) && date('m') == 9 && date('d') == 2){

    echo 'To speak to an attorney about this practice area, please call XXX-XXX-XXXX';
    } elseif (date('m') == 10 && date('d') == 16) {
    echo 'To speak to an attorney about this practice area, please call XXX-XXX-XXXX';
    }

 ?>
```

You were using too many brackets.

Comment: No problem, good luck. If it helped solve your problem, feel free to mark it as correct so others who have the same problem as you will know how you fixed it.